# What is the difference between travel to, travel in, and travel?

Tags: prepositions

Can I say "I am traveling to Seoul next week" or "I am traveling in Seoul next week" or "I am traveling Seoul next week"? What is the difference between these sentences?

Answer (score 0):

"I am traveling to Seoul" implies that you will be journeying from somewhere else to Seoul.

"I am traveling in Seoul" implies that you will be traveling around within the boundaries of Seoul (and perhaps associated communities).

"I am traveling Seoul" is less idiomatic in most English-speaking communities, but it suggests you will be touring around within Seoul, probably as a tourist.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! Very helpful !